# $\int_0^1 f(x)^2\le 1$ and $\int_0^1 f'(x)^2\le 1$ $\Rightarrow$ $\left|f(x)\right|\le \sqrt3$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, inequality

Let $f:[0, 1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function that is continous on $[0,1]$ and derivable on $(0, 1)$. If $\int_0^1 f(x)^2\le 1$ and $\int_0^1 f'(x)^2\le 1$, show that $\left|f(x)\right|\le \sqrt3$ for all $x\in [0, 1]$.

Using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality I've shown that $\left|f(x)-f(0)\right|\le \sqrt{x}$ and $\left|f(x)^2-f(0)^2\right|\le 2$. Any other ideas?

Comment: are you saying that $|f(x)| \leq \sqrt{3}$ for all x or just in some range?

Comment: $\forall x\in [0, 1]$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I think I have a proof.

By mean value theorem for integral, there exists $\xi\in [0, 1]$ such that $f(\xi)^2=\int_0^1 f(x)^2 dx\le 1$. Suppose $x> \xi$ (if $x\le \xi$ we can give a similar proof), by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
$$\left| \frac{f(x)^2-f(\xi)^2}{2} \right |=\left| \int_{\xi}^x f(t)f'(t)dt \right|\le \left( \int_{\xi}^x f(t)^2 dt \right)^{1/2}\left( \int_{\xi}^x f'(t)^2 dt \right)^{1/2}\le 1.$$
We conclude that $f(x)^2\le 3$ for all $x\in [0, 1]$.

Comment: really nice solution +1.

Answer (score 0):

Take a function that has a narrow spike, like:
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
          \frac{x}{a^2}       & 0 \le x \le a \\
          \frac{2 a - x}{a^2} & a <   x \le 2 a \\
          0                   & 2 a < x
       \end{cases}
$$
This function's maximal value is $a$, you have $\int_0^1 f(x) \mathrm{d} x = 1$, but I believe you'll find you can make the integrals as small as you wish by adjusting $a$.

Comment: Are you showing a counterexample?

Comment: I believe so. The point is that the maximal value of the function is a *local* matter, the integrals a *global* one.

Comment: I don't think you're right. Read all the hypotheses again.

Comment: @vonbrand: I have not worked through your example, but I strongly suspect that there is something wrong with it.  The conditions can be summarised as an upper bound on the $H^1$ norm. In one dimension, we have a continuous embedding into the continuous functions, so that we have a pointwise bound.

Comment: @vonbrand: If only the integral of $f(x)$ was restricted then your function would have served as a counterexample. But here the integral of $\{f'(x)\}^{2}$ is also restricted and this will limit the values of $f(x)$.